# I want my app to be running in a (Thread or as a service) even when onDestroy() is called (user removed from background)

Tags: java, android, ios, android-studio, service

I am trying to keep my application alive even after user has removed it from background, but the service it provide should be running. Is there a way to do it?

I am new to android, any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to create ForegroundService. Check out more here:

https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it.

Comment: Cool, what was exactly the problem you had?